# Jasper plugin for Eclipse does not working after software update

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, jaspersoft-studio

I had installed `STS 3.9.5` with `Jaspersoft Studio 6.6.0` plugin and everything worked fine until I have updated software to versions `3.9.7` / `6.9.0`. After that, `jrxml` files can't be displayed with the `JasperReports Designer` in Eclipse. Only blank page is showed. Did anyone have this problem?

I have tried with multiple restarts/cleans but no success. A console doesn't show any error.

Thanks.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a message there.

Comment: I have already looked, there are no Jasper related messages.

Comment: did you update the existing install? if so, what happens if you install the Jasper plugins into a fresh STS distribution?

Comment: @MartinLippert yes, I have updated the existing install. Fresh install would probably solve this issue, but the circumstances are such that I can only update an existing software.

Comment: @akelec this makes debugging this a bit more complicated, but if you want to, you can open a console view, switch to "Host OSGi Console", and type in "ss" (for short status). It lists all the installed bundles. If there is anything in the "INSTALLED" state, that is suspicious. In that case, you could run "diag <bundle-number>" to see the reason and post it here (by updating the question). That might reveal more details, in case this is related to some incompatibilities (just guessing here).